# How to loop through multiple optional fields to insert to database

Tags: php, mysql, fat-free-framework

I am building an admin form to insert a new quiz with questions and options. Each quiz has multiple questions, each question can have just one optiontype ('trueorfalse', 'monthsoftheyear' -> these are rendered on the display end so I don't need to create multiple options because they are predicatable) or multiple custom options (so the optiontype="CUSTOM" for that question and each option has it's own text field).

This is how the database would look like:

```
QUESTION 
id / text                               /  ... other  irrelevant fields
13 / this is the true or false question /  ...
14 / this is a custom question          / ...

CHOICES 
id / question_id / optiontype  / text
24 / 13          / trueorfalse / null
25 / 14          / CUSTOM      / red
26 / 14          / CUSTOM      / blue
27 / 14          / CUSTOM      / ...and so on fir the other custom options





    function save($f3){     
        // save the user's results to the database  
        $newquiz = new Quizzes ($this->db);

        $newquiz->copyfrom('POST', function($val) {
            return array_intersect_key($val, array_flip(array('name','description')));
        });         
        $newquiz->save();

        $question = new Questions ($this->db);
        $choice = new Choices ($this->db);
        foreach($f3->get('POST.question') as $q) {          
            $question->reset();
            $text = $q['text'];
            $byline = $q['byline'];
            $correctanswer = $q['correctanswer'];           
            $answerwriteup = $q['answerwriteup'];
            $optiontype = $q['optiontype'];         

            $question->quiz_id_fk = $newquiz->_id;
            $question->text = $text;
            $question->byline = $byline;
            $question->correctanswer = $correctanswer;
            $question->answerwriteup = $answerwriteup;

            $question->save();

            $questionid = $question->id;

            if ($optiontype != 'CUSTOM') {
                $choice->reset();
                $choice->question_id_fk = $questionid;
                $choice->optiontype = $optiontype;
                $choice->save();
            }

 // everything above this comment works perfectly fine. It's the section below that I have trouble with: 

            if ($optiontype == 'CUSTOM') {
                $choice->reset();
                $choice->question_id_fk = $questionid;
                $choice->optiontype = $optiontype;
                // how do I get the text fields for each option
                $choice->save();
            }
        }
        $f3->reroute('/admin');
    }
}
```

The insert form on the admin page has a SELECT input field for optiontype. The admin can select "trueorfalse" or "months" or "CUSTOM" as options. If they select "trueorfalse" or "months", there is no further input. However, if they select CUSTOM, I use jquery to unhide another 6 text fields for the CUSTOM options (for simplicity, assume there are always 6 options). The admin can then type the text for the CUSTOM options ('red','green', etc). See the image below for reference.

My question: How do I handle the CUSTOM option save to database? I think it should be some sort of foreach loop, but i don't know what exactly to loop through.

This is the form code (there is some jquery below that I've excluded that doesn't really affect the code logic):

```
<loop from="{{ @i=1 }}" to="{{ @i < 11 }}" step="{{ @i++ }}">            
    <img src="{{@BASE}}/app/views/images/black.jpg" width="100%" height="1px">
    <label class="text-right col-sm-3" for="question{{@i}}">Question {{@i}}</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-9">
        <input name="question[{{@i}}][text]" id="question{{@i}}_text" type="hidden">
        <div id="editor_{{@i}}" style="height:100px; margin-bottom: 20px "></div>  
    </div> 

    <label class="text-right col-sm-3"  >Q{{@i}} Byline</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-9">
        <input id="question1_byline " type="text" class="form-control " name="question[{{@i}}][byline]">
    </div> 

    <label class="text-right col-sm-3"  >Q{{@i}} Correct Answer</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-9">
        <input   type="text" class="form-control  " name="question[{{@i}}][correctanswer]">
    </div>

    <label class="text-right col-sm-3"  >Q{{@i}} Answer Writeup</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-9">
        <input name="question[{{@i}}][answerwriteup]" id="question{{@i}}_answerwriteup" type="hidden">
        <div id="editor_answer{{@i}}" style="height:100px; margin-bottom: 20px "></div>                    
    </div> 

    <label class="text-right col-sm-3" for="question{{@i}}_optiontype">Q{{@i}} Option Type</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-9">
        <select id="question{{@i}}_optiontype" class="form-control" data-role="select"  name="question[{{@i}}][optiontype]">
            <option value="100percent">100percent</option>
            <option value="trueorfalse" selected>trueorfalse</option>
            <option value="realorfake" selected>realorfake</option>
            <option value="months">months</option>
            <option value="CUSTOM">CUSTOM</option>
        </select>                    
    </div> 

    <label class="text-right col-sm-3"  >Q{{@i}} CUSTOM OPTIONS (only if CUSTOM was selected)</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-9" id="customoption{{@i}}" style="display:none">
        <div class="col-xs-2"><input   type="text" class="form-control  " name="question[{{@i}}][custom]"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2"><input   type="text" class="form-control  " name="question[{{@i}}][custom]"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2"><input   type="text" class="form-control  " name="question[{{@i}}][custom]"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2"><input   type="text" class="form-control  " name="question[{{@i}}][custom]"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2"><input   type="text" class="form-control  " name="question[{{@i}}][custom]"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2"><input   type="text" class="form-control  " name="question[{{@i}}][custom]"></div>
    </div>

</loop>
```

[This is a snapshot of the admin form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6lj7.png)

Comment: check for the 'CUSTOM' value then loop through the special input fields by name. Add [] to the name of these input fields in your form, otherwise the values get overwritten and you will only receive the last entered value.

Comment: I figured as much, but I'm not aware of the precise code to use to loop through just the CUSTOM fields for that particular question. Any clue?
Also, each CUSTOM option is its own record.